# Developed MS Surface Application. Now how do I actually run it on one?

Tags: visual-studio, pixelsense

My partner and I have created a Surface Application for our research project. It is working properly on the Surface Simulator that is launched when running Visual Studio on our laptops.

The actual MS Surface is in another department and we are setting up a meeting with the professor who owns it. I was wondering how to run this application on the MS Surface. Do I just copy the compiled ".exe" file onto the Surface with a USB? Or do I have to copy the whole project folder and run Visual Studio and recompile on the Surface itself? I know the Surface runs Vista so would we be able to access it or is there some other process? Seems like a trivial task, but it's just something that we are completely unfamiliar with so I'd appreciate any help.

Cheers,
jacob

Answer (score 1):

- If all you want to do is run it to **see how it looks on the device** then you **just copy the .exe and any files it depends on** to the surface device (using USB or network). This is usually just a matter of copying the `bin/Debug` folder to the device. To run it, just double click on the .exe and it'll display itself on the surface screen.
- If you want to do a **proper deployment**, then you need to do what Randolf explained in his answer, namely to **register the application with the surface shell** as outlined in the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee804900%28Surface.10%29.aspx).
- If you want to **debug your application**, then you obviously need to run it through visual studio. The easiest way to do this is as you mention yourself to **copy the source to the device and open it on Visual studio on the surface**. I'd recommend you hook up your surface device to your source code management system (e.g. TFS or similar) and checkout a copy on the surface machine.

  - It is also possible to do [remote debugging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bt727f1t%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) in Visual Studio. This allows you to debug from your developer machine and have the code running on the surface device. It would require you do copy the .exe as explained in step 1 above and also enable remote debugging. I've never tried this, as I found it easier to just debug directly on the surface.